# Table is not mapped?

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

Now to my understanding to map a table in db we add:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test implements Serializable {
    /** Constant - serial version UID. */
    public final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** Member variable - represents the "name" field. */
    public String name;
}
```

but for some reason when I do query:

```
delete from test;
```

it gives me this error:

```
15:55:54,140 ERROR [JsonFilter] javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: spa_splash_page_ad is not mapped [delete from spa_splash_page_ad]
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: spa_splash_page_ad is not mapped [delete from spa_splash_page_ad]
    at com.pinksheets.common.web.servlet.DeleteSplashPageServlet.fetch(DeleteSplashPageServlet.java:30)
    at com.pinksheets.common.web.servlet.DeleteSplashPageServlet.fetch(DeleteSplashPageServlet.java:17)
```

any idea why it is doing that?

Comment: What is the code for the testValue class?

Comment: test value will be only variables for the primary key..

Comment: Yes, but you must have matching members in your main class if you are using `@IdClass`. See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html

Comment: @chris 
ya i realize that theres no composite key so i removed it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete from table test` isn't a valid query in any QL I know of.

A class mapped as `@IdClass` is a composite id, and you'd never delete it directly. You would delete an entity that has that as its id. Also since it's an `@IdClass`, I'm not sure what to expect when you give it an explicit `@Table` mapping. An `@IdClass` is a primary key value and is always supposed to be used as an id of some other class. It doesn't have its own table. See the hibernate annotations reference for [mapping composite ids](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177) and correct [use of `@IdClass`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1112).

Comment: ya i kinda figured that out after review the table, thought it had composite ids.. thanks!

still getting the not mapped error, im guessing my mentor probably has a different way of doing things

Comment: So the next question would be why you're trying to write a delete query instead of simply calling `session.delete(someObject)`.

Comment: even though the table is mapped its still giving me the error guess ill wait for my mentor to look over everything...

Answer (score 2):

1. Try:

   `delete from com.mycompany.database.Test`
   read about [fully qualified names](http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/usingpackages.htm) (it is the full package name/path + the class name )
2. Why is the word `table`  in the query?
3. Also remove the `()` from the `@Entity()`
4. you should keep the java convention, name your entities with capital starting letters:

   `class Test{}`
   than you can:

   `delete from fully.qualified.name.Test`
5. Make sure the the Entity is `@javax.persistence.Entity` and not something else.

Comment: sry that was an error there shouldnt be a table anywhere in delete..

fully.qualified.name.test what does this mean?? just type that in?

() is in there because i used one of the senior devs work as example so she had it there so i added that as well... ill try again..